# ko.observable(), check (and maybe update) value before use

Tags: knockout.js

For example we have:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: num1, valueUpdate: 'keyup'"/>
<input type="text" data-bind="value: num2, valueUpdate: 'keyup'"/>
<input type="text" data-bind="value: total"/>


var viewModel = {
    num1: ko.observable(0),
    num2: ko.observable(0)
};

viewModel.total = ko.computed(function () {
    return parseFloat(viewModel.num1()) + parseFloat(viewModel.num2());
}, viewModel);

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Is it possible to check if `num1` and`num2` contains `,`? If yes, I need to replace it with `.` before calculating `viewModel.total`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gbos/gmNJR/1/) illustrates a solution applying extensions to observables using [ko extenders](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/extenders.html).

Answer (score 2):

I would add a couple of computed observables in there to do the parsing:

```
    var viewModel = {  
        num1: ko.observable(0),  
        num2: ko.observable(0)  
    };  

   viewModel.num1Parsed = ko.computed(function () {  
        return viewModel.num1().replaceAll(',', '.');  
    }, viewModel);  

   viewModel.num2Parsed = ko.computed(function () {  
        return viewModel.num2().replaceAll(',', '.');  
    }, viewModel);  

    viewModel.total = ko.computed(function () {  
        return parseFloat(viewModel.num1Parsed()) + parseFloat(viewModel.num2Parsed());  
    }, viewModel);
```

I use the following function for replaceAll:

```
/** 
* ReplaceAll by Fagner Brack (MIT Licensed) 
* Replaces all occurrences of a substring in a string 
*/
String.prototype.replaceAll = function (token, newToken, ignoreCase) {
    var str, i = -1, _token;
    if ((str = this.toString()) && typeof token === "string") {
        _token = ignoreCase === true ? token.toLowerCase() : undefined;
        while ((i = (
        _token !== undefined ?
            str.toLowerCase().indexOf(
                        _token,
                        i >= 0 ? i + newToken.length : 0
            ) : str.indexOf(
                        token,
                        i >= 0 ? i + newToken.length : 0
            )
    )) !== -1) {
            str = str.substring(0, i)
                .concat(newToken)
                .concat(str.substring(i + token.length));
        }
    }
    return str;
};
```

Alternatively, you could just replace your num1 and num2 observables in the HTML with a computed that parses as the value is written to it:

```
    this.num1Parsed = ko.dependentObservable({
        read: function () {
            return viewModel.num1();
        },
        write: function (value) {
            viewModel.num1(value.replaceAll(',', '.'));
        },
        owner: this
    });

    this.num2Parsed = ko.dependentObservable({
        read: function () {
            return viewModel.num2();
        },
        write: function (value) {
            viewModel.num2(value.replaceAll(',', '.'));
        },
        owner: this
    });
```

.. and then change your HTML to:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: num1Parsed, valueUpdate: 'keyup'"/>             
<input type="text" data-bind="value: num2Parsed, valueUpdate: 'keyup'"/>             
<input type="text" data-bind="value: total"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The easiest way would be to just call Javascripts string replace function such as

```
var temp1 = viewModel.num1().replace(',','.');
```

This will not only look for a comma, but will replace it if it is found at the same time.

NOTE: This will only work with a single comma since floats should only have a single period. If any other comma or period is inserted the numbers after the comma/period will be ignored.

See fiddle for example http://jsfiddle.net/Rynan/LYzhx/

Comment: thx for reply. the problem is not in the replace function ), the problem is where can i use it, so i won't need to update every ko.computed() where i used num1 and num2